# Which hand will be used for which spell?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After investing a few thousand septims into spell books I am pretty much left stranded as I didn't know which spell is being used for which hand. I prefer wielding one projectile-type spell and one close-range spell.

Is there a way to determine which hand will be used for which spell? Is there a compiled list of all spells somewhere I can refer to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any spell in either hand.  When you select the spell, left clicking will put it in your right hand and right clicking will put it in your left hand.

Comment: This is true, while it seems backwards.. I would highly recommend getting a 360 controller to connect to your PC for this game where the right trigger then matches your right hand and the left its counter part.. The controls of the game are significantly improved since I swapped over to the controller.

Comment: @James I had to rewrite this 3 times because my brain wouldn't let me write such backwardsness

Comment: @James Overcoming the awkwardness of the left/right mixup is much easier for some than the awkwardness of aiming with a joystick.

Comment: @StrixVaria I guess having played all the Fallout games on the 360 instead of PC that I am used to the aiming on a controller. But honestly, aiming was not even a consideration in my comment. The enter button being 'Yes' makes me have to disrupt the flow of the game to strike it. It becomes even more bothersome when the overall Yes/No box that pops up when exiting crafting stations or selecting level up stats -requires- the mouse to click it, and then doesn't consume the mouses input and clicks whatever was behind it. For me it allows me to enjoy the game much more with acceptable trade-offs

Comment: @StrixVaria There was a time when I would generally agree with your statement, as I used to be primarily a PC gamer.  However, after having put nearly 200 hours into Skyrim on the PS3, I don't think I'd feel quite right playing it with a keyboard and mouse.  I will say that the right/left clicking inversion would probably make more sense for right-handed people though.  They already have the mind-set that their right hand is their primary hand, and the left is the alternate.  So, having the left (or primary) click work the right hand does sort of fit.

Comment: If you intend to use two spells or two weapons, it's probably worth the time to rebind the mouse buttons so the left controls the left hand and the right the right hand. That's how I ended up with a left-handed conjurer

Comment: @Iszi quite right! I'm right-handed and only after reading these comments has it hit my mind that the controls are actually inverted, they feel very natural!